# How to show entries related to main category

Tags: categories, tags

I have an entry with the following category and subcategory

```
-Crops
---fruit
----papaya (Main)
```

The problem is that when I show the related articles, it shows me all the entries of the category (`crops`) and not of the subcategory that you select as main (`papaya`)

this is the code i have:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'post_tag');

$args = array (
'category__not_in'           => $tags,
    'post__not_in' => array(get_the_ID()),
    'posts_per_page'         => '10',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id',
    );


$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) { ?>
    <section class="entry-related">
        <h3>Articulos relacionados</h3>
        <div class="flex flex-fluid">
            <?php
            while ($query->have_posts()) {
                $query->the_post();
                get_template_part('template-parts/loops/loop', 'related');
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </section>

    <?php
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

How would you show me only the entries in the subcategory that I select as the main one?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with that code

## Selecting the wrong terms

First of all, you are storing tags instead of categories in the `$terms` variable. The taxonomy name for categories is `category`. That line should look like this.

```
$categories = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category');
```

For sake of expresivity, I changed the `$terms` variable to `$categories`.

## Wrong query parameter for categories

You are using `category__not_in`, telling the query **NOT** to search for posts with those caregories. It is not only returning posts from `crops`, it returning every post that doesn't has the current category.

In order to tell the query that you want posts from a category or group of categories, you should use `category__in`

You can see more about accepted args for the `WP_Query` [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters)

## Wrong value for category__in

The `category__in` parameter for the query takes as value either a string or an array of categories ids (strings). The items stored in the `$categories` array are instances of `WP_Term`.

In order to pass the right value, you should create an array of ids from the array of `WP_Term`. We can get a `WP_Term` id by accesing the `term_id` property.

```
'category__in'           => array_map(function($cat){ return $cat->term_id; }, $categories)
```

`array_map` returns every item from the array after aplying a callback function to each of them. In this case, we are making an array of terms_ids from the `$categories` array.

## Final Result

This is how your query should look like

```
$categories = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category');

$args = array (
    'category__in'                  => array_map(function($cat){ return $cat->term_id; }, $categories),
    'post__not_in'                  => array(get_the_ID()),
    'posts_per_page'                => '10',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'           => 1,
    'meta_key'                      => '_thumbnail_id',
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```